# how to build APK files for applications developed using Flet (python)

Tags: android, flutter, apk, flet

in flutter i can build APK files for Android applications using

```
flutter build apk
```

how to build APK files for applications developed using Flet (python)?

Answer (score 2):

And here we come. Flet works on Android now. Flet is a server-driven ui framework, so apk files are just webview. Anyway, it's enough to me. Have a nice work! [Flet Blog Page](https://flet.dev/blog/flet-for-android/)

Answer (score 1):

flet currently does not have support for mobile platforms. But it will be soon.

Take a look [here](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/mobile-support).