# Integrate python with flutter for library consumption

Tags: python, flutter, psutil

I'm developing a personal project in Flutter that aims to collect some user information such as (ram memory, hardware information, etc.).

Flutter does not provide a complete package for this idea, so I wanted to do this Python integration using the psutil library, how do I proceed...

Comment: I don't know if it possible, but there is framework [flet](https://flet.dev/) which uses Python to generate `flutter app`. maybe you should check its source code.

Comment: as I know `psutil` uses some Linux commands to get information - like `ps`, `free`, `htop`, etc. So you could use them to get data (without using Python) if you only know how to run system command in `Flutter` (similar to `subprocess.run()` in `Python`). And if you find in source code what tools `psutil` uses.

Comment: Flet is not viable because as far as I know you cannot build the apk

Comment: it is strange. In documentation they have [Testing Flet app on Android](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/testing-on-android). And I found also this: [android - how to build APK files for applications developed using Flet (python) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73921270/how-to-build-apk-files-for-applications-developed-using-flet-python). But I'm rather afraid it may not be good idea if you have own code in Flutter because it may not gives direct access to Flutter code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to embed Python runtime to a Flutter app, you can try [serious_python](https://github.com/flet-dev/serious-python#serious_python).

But if you're trying to collect user information as mentioned above, you might want to try [writing custom platform-specific code](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels).